# Django add Count annotation to a prefetch related query that is filtered

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django version 1.11 and I'm trying to execute the following query.

```
queryset = Series.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
             'issues',queryset=Issue.objects.filter(hide=False)
        )
     )
    .filter(hide=False, issues__hide=False)
    .annotate('issue_count=Count('issues')
)
```

The query runs perfectly fine the issue is that the annotated issue_count value is not correct. Instead of it reading back the count of the prefetch queryset it is just reading back the entire related issues property.

Any suggestions??

Comment: That's normal, the prefetch an annotation are *independent* parts.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess I'm wondering how I would get the count of the filtered prefetch queryset issues then? My goal is to eventually be able to do a issue_count__gte=0.

Comment: This post helped me resolve it. But because I'm using Django 1.11 I need to use a SubQuery within the annotate() call to get the value back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using Django 1.11 in annotations you have to use a subquery to achieve the desired count of the filtered relationship.

```
queryset = Series.objects.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('issue_series', queryset=Issue.objects.filter(hide=False).filter(issue_query_set))) \
            .filter(hide=False) \
            .annotate(issue_count=Subquery(
                    Issue.objects.filter(
                        series=OuterRef('pk'),
                        hide=False
                    )
                    .filter(issue_query_set)
                    .values('series')
                    .annotate(cnt=Count('pk'))
                    .values('cnt'),
                    output_field=IntegerField()
                )
            )\
            .filter(issue_count__gt=0)
```